# PHP MySQL error- I'm not logged into the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP. I need some help.

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for
>   user 'bp6am'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\video\dbb.php on line 3 unable to connect. check your
>   connection parameters.

I know I'm not logged into the database but I'm not able to get through it.

```
   db.inc.php
       <?php
          define('MYSQL_HOST','localhost');
          define('MYSQL_USER','root');
          define('MYSQL_PASSWORD','pass');
          define('MYSQL_DB','chat');
          ?>
    dbb.php
      <?php
       require 'db.inc.php';
       $db= mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass') OR
      die('unable to connect. check your connection parameters.');
        mysql_select_db(chat,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
      // create the user table
        $query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
         site user(
        user_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO INCREMENT,
          username VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       password CHAR(41) NOT NULL,

       PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
          }
        ENGINE=MYISAM';
          mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
         //create the user info table
          $query = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
          site user_info(
         user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
          last_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        city  VARCHAR(20)
       state CHAR(2)
       hobbies VARCHAR(255) 
       FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES site_user(user_id)
        }
       ENGINE=MYISAM';
        mysql_select_db(chat,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));

         //populate the user table
          $query='INSERT IGNORE INTO site_user
              (user_id,username,password)
          VALUES
      (1,"niharika",PASSWORD("niharika")),
      (2,"admin",PASSWORD("admin"))';
         mysql_select_db(chat,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
       //populate the user information table 
        $query='INSERT IGNORE INTO site_user_inefo
      (user_id,first_name,last_name,email,city,state,hobbies)
         VALUES
     (1."niharika","katyan","niharikatyan@gmail.com",NULL,NULL,NULL),
        (1."admin","smith","adminsmith@gmail.com",NULL,NULL,NULL)';
          mysql_select_db(chat,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
       echo 'success!';
      ?>
```

Comment: Is the xamp server running/online?

Comment: access denied means you're using the wrong password, or the `GRANT` you did for that user was incorrect.

Comment: @coder1984: if it wasn't running, you couldn't get access denied. it'd be "connection refused" or "timed out" or whatever.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

You missed quotes around the DB name,

```
mysql_select_db('chat',$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

Answer (score 1):

Break the problem down into more simple steps.

For example, save the following into its own file, test.php:

```
$db= mysql_connect('localhost','root','pass') OR die('unable to connect. check your connection parameters.');
mysql_select_db('chat',$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```

In the browser, try going to `localhost/test.php` and see what happens.

Do the same any time you get stuck like that.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you get means that either username or password or both are misspelled. Check those and you should be good.

Maybe you switched them? Is `bp6am` the password? ;)

Answer (score 0):

be sure about the path of this file. if its in same place where dbb.php

porobably u didnt reach this file of connection to database
and change this also

replace this

```
   mysql_select_db(chat,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```

by

```
  mysql_select_db("chat") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php): *Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument*. And it would throw a fatal error if it failed.